# LCC Resonance Converter

Tags: power-electronics, resonant-converter, llc-converter

I am trying to understand and design a LCC Converter

I read lots of documents about LLC and read "Design of efficient LCC based on ICL5102/HV combo controller IC" for LCC, I think I have a decent amount of knowledge about the working principles but I have no idea about the selection of components, while there are lots of design guides about LLC I could not find a good design guide for LCC converter and the one infineon provides is using a tool which is kind of black box. And the tool does not let me go to the Vout of 2000 V (which I needed it in my project). Is there a design guide (application note) for a LCC converter ? Or do you suggest anything to me ?

Thanks in advance